# SQL Server time column returns wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a query in SQL Server and in this query I select a `TIME` column.

So I use:

```
SELECT
    TOA.RECEIPTTIMEREQUESTED
FROM 
    TRANSPORTORDERTABLE TOA
```

result is 28800 in a certain row instead of 08:00, or 52200 instead of 14:30

What should is do to get the right time result in my query?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the number of seconds since midnight.  So, try this:

```
select dateadd(second, receipttimerequested, 0)
```

If you want this as a `time`:

```
select cast(dateadd(second, receipttimerequested, 0) as time)
```